# Angular2 - Best way to implement shopping cart?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am working on my **Angular2/Ionic2** app, I came across to step where I really don't know what's the best option to go with.
Currently I have a page, in which the user can add items to a cart, what I want to do is to **store** the added items somewhere in the user device; so he/she can check what's on the cart no matter if the user opens other views/pages an can modify quantities on that cart, etc....

What on my mind now is to **push** the added items to an **array**, then store them in the user device using the **local storage**, I really don't know if it is the good/best way to do it. That's why I want to hear your opinions guys!

**Please share your thoughts, ideas and best practices**.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds fine. Create a service where you implement the reading and writing to localstorage, inject it to where you want access the shopping cart (some component or other service) and call read, add, delete methods on the localstorage service.

Comment: All of the blogs say to use a BehaviorSubject, and how great that is, never mention localstorage at all, and when I refresh, the cart contents goes by-by. Is this just hype causing everyone to lose their minds?

Comment: These are to different but complementary things. Using observables (like BehaviorSubject, and others) can make code easier to write and understand, but it's not related to persistence. You can decide to persist the items on a server identified by a cookie or a key stored in LocalStorage or store the whole shopping card in LocalStorage. So it's not about a hype, it's just about different aspects of your application.